# Capistrano & Magento - Previewing new deploy and manually update symlink

Tags: composer, deploy

I am using a Capistrano deployment workflow for a Magento project.

On deploy Capistrano builds this Magento project on the server using https://github.com/Cotya/magento-composer-installer.

The issue is sometimes my Magento modules don't install correctly and I need to clear the cache, reindex or some other task to get everything 100%. The issues occur sporadically so I haven't been able to script a fix into the deployment process.

What I would like is on deploy Capistrano does not change the symlink to the new build straight away. Instead I am able to preview the site on another link, fix what needs to be fixed, then change the symlink manually.

Is this possible to set up using Capistrano?

If not, my other solution to this is to use the Magento maintenance flag however I would rather avoid having to put the site in maintenance. Open to other idea's as well!

Thanks